# My wordpress theme name isn't updating straight away

Tags: theme-development, themes, cache

My theme name in the metadata is defined in `style.css` as

```
Theme Name: No Contrast
```

```
Theme Name: Lap of Luxury
```

But when I refresh the page in "manage themes" the theme name doesn't update.  Instead it says

> no-contrast

> lapofluxury

Why?

I'm using wordpress 5.7.2

Comment: this data gets cached for performance reasons, if you switch to another theme then back it should update

Answer (score 0):

I happens to me all the time css not updating! if not css error! normally is the browser.
Maybe cleaning the browser cache?! in most browsers  ctrl + shift + del.